# display word/pdf file in web page from database

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, filestream

I have word,pdf files in my db sql. I want to show them in a new page while click on link. In list page I use the following code:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Resume">        
                       <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />                  
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <a href ='<%#"ViewProfile.aspx?ProfileID="+DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ProfileID") %>' id="hlprofile">View Profile</a>                  
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

In page load of ViewProfile.aspx.cs I have the following:

```
 int id = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["ProfileID"]);
 string embed = "<object data=\"{0}{1}\" type=\"application/pdf\"  width=\"1100px\" height=\"700px\">";
                          embed += "If you are unable to view file, you can download from <a href = \"{0}{1}&download=1\">here</a>";
                          embed += " or download <a target = \"_blank\" href = \"http://get.adobe.com/reader/\">Adobe PDF Reader</a> to view the file.";
                          embed += "</object>";

                          ltEmbed.Text = string.Format(embed, ResolveUrl("~/FileView.ashx?ProfileID="), id);
```

and in FileView.ashx.cs I include the following :

```
int proID = int.Parse(context.Request.QueryString["ProfileID"]);
            byte[] bytes;
            string fileName, contentType;

            DataTable ds = new DataTable();
              ds = objProfile.GetResume(proID);
            if (ds.Rows.Count == 1)
            {
                foreach (DataRow dRow in ds.Rows)
                {
                    bytes = (byte[])dRow["Resume"];
                    fileName = dRow["ResumeName"].ToString();
                    contentType = dRow["ContentType"].ToString();

                    context.Response.Buffer = true;
                    context.Response.Charset = "";
                    if (context.Request.QueryString["download"] == "1")
                    {
                        context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
                    }


                      if (contentType == "application/vnd.ms-word")
                        {
                            context.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-word";
                        }
                        else if (contentType == "application/pdf")
                          {
                              context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                             }
                      context.Response.Charset = "";
                      context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

                    //context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                    context.Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
                    context.Response.Flush();
                    context.Response.End();
                }
            }
```

For PDF files it shows the file without fail, but for content type as word 'application/vnd.ms-word' it's not working. I think to change 'type' in `<object>` which is in ViewProfile page.

Can anyone help me to do this?

Comment: Your word document is a .docx or a .doc ?

Comment: .docx and in db i have saved its contentType as "application/vnd.ms-word"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Word **.docx**

```
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
```

instead of `application/vnd.ms-word` => (**.doc**)

Comment: I tried this but not working.. my doubt is "string embed = "<object data=\"{0}{1}\" type=\"application/pdf\"  width=\"1100px\" height=\"700px\">";" in this line can we change to support for word doc. too?